# Django: uploading resized images to AWS S3 using django-store-redux and PIL

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, django-storage

I'm having strange problem with saving re-sized images to AWS S3. Here's my code which is executed after an instance is saved:

```
def create_picture(instance, max_length, max_width):
    # Load image file
    img = Image.open(instance.picture)

    # Resize an image
    size = (max_length, max_width)
    img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    print(img.size) #this shows proper size now

    # Update image file
    fh = storage.open(instance.picture.name, "w")
    img.save(fh, 'PNG')
    fh.close()

    return True
```

This code in principle works fine if I specify 'PNG' format, however, since PNG increases file size by 10 times, I'd like to store it as 'JPEG'.  And that's where the problems start. Using 'JPEG' instead of 'PNG' and saving the file doesn't seem to do storing the right size, in fact, it doesn't seem to do anything with the file. Also, there are no errors/warnings. 
An alternative solution could be to change the quality of PNG, I tried to set quality=10 when saving an img, but this also doesn't seem to do anything...

Many thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Check out ImageMagick

Comment: I don't think it's a conversion problem. PIL works just fine when using paths.

Comment: Did you try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204199/4018857